# What can change the world?

Tags: ios, imaginary-range

I'm stuck on page 28 of chapter/episode 2 of Imaginary Range and I need an item to continue. It says:

> Look for an item hidden in the floating castle frame that can change the world

I checked the earlier pages, especially the ones with floating islands, and I didn't find any obvious items to pick up.

What item do I need to continue and where do I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently on page 22 there's a floating PAD blueprint. It's in the panel where someone is saying "No, I've got something else in mind for you."

It's green with a golden PAD dagger in the middle, in the right of the frame. It looks sort of like part of the scene, but it's not. Circle it with your finger to pick it up and use it at page 28 and you can continue.